# Cannot hit breakpoints in Maven Project while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, debugging

I've been searching high and low for a tutorial on how to debug Maven projects in Eclipse and I've been changing Debug Configurations, running mvn commands in the terminal and I just can't hit my breakpoints. I'm running a UI application and the application won't even open, at the end of the debugging session I get a "Build Success" message in the console. 
I've tried creating the following Debugging configurations:

```
Goal: -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
Parameter Name: forkCount
Value = 0

Goal: test
Parameter Name:-Dmaven.surefire.debug
Value:true
```

I've also tried [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-eclipse-remote-debugging.html) but have had no success.

I also ran these commands in the terminal:

```
 mvnDebug -Dtest=TestClass#testMethod test -DforkMode=never

 mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
```

Can anyone please give me exact steps on how I can hit my breakpoints? I've been researching but I just can't achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you cannot debug, your IDE do not look at the same classes as the JVM running the code to be debugged. Check your artifacts.

Comment: The artifacts in the pom.xml file all look correct, the project runs fine if run it normally. The plugin for the maven surefire is like so:  <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>

Comment: Would you like to debug your Test or Maven itself ?

Comment: I want to debug my project that I have written as a Maven Project, so would I consider that wanting to debug a Test or a Maven?

Comment: I assume you would like to debug a Test which can simply being done from the IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) Just run the unit Tests with Debug Mode...no need to debug Maven itself...

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly how to run the unit tests with debug mode? I've been trying to follow this tutorial : http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2014/11/19/debugging-with-maven-and-eclipse/ and all I get on the command line is build success. I'm lost on exactly what I should do because every time I follow these steps, I still can't hit the break points. And I've been trying a few things that I found online. I've set my project folder as the source lookup path but still nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to debug your tests while running in Maven? If you want to debug a unit test, just right-click and select "Debug As" and select "JUnit Test".

Comment: Alright so I read up on what exactly a unit test is and what it's used for (I'm fairly new to Maven and it's debugging ways) and what I need is not to test methods individually but to test my project as a whole because everything is connected together. I have my threads and my user interface which I can't run individually because I need to test them together. I hope I've made sense. How can I do this?